# Как сделать стрелки для навигации слайдера с помощью CSS3?

Tags: css3, slider

Как сделать, чтобы стрелки слайдера плавно появлялись при ховере, - [как на примере FlexSlider](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/)?

[image: пример]

Comment: Что именно с ними сделать? Такое же появление плавное?

Comment: Да, плавное появление при ховере.

Comment: Пожалуйста, опишите задачу полностью в вопросе. Через некоторое время ссылка может стать нерабочей и вопрос потеряет смысл.

Comment: Ответ дан. Задача решена. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Основная идея в том что надо скрыть стрелки за пределами слайдера, указав им значение left и right -50px при position: absolute. Выставить при наведении эти значения в положительные. И добавить плавность с помощью transition.

```css
#slider{
    width: 500px;
    height: 150px;
    background: blue;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.arrow{
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    top: 46%;
    background: #fff;
    opacity: 0;

    transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.left{
    left: -20px;
 }

.right{
    right: -20px;
}

#slider:hover .left{
    left: 20px;
    opacity: 1;
}

#slider:hover .right{
    right: 20px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
    <div class="arrow left"></div>
    <div class="arrow right"></div>
</div>
```